# contenteditable injected in the DOM is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I created an editable field based on "contenteditable="true" and it is working well. Content is saved to the database when the user clicks out of the div (blur).

However, when I inject an additional field with Jquery after the first one, the new field does not send content to the database when the user clicks out of the div.

I reproduced the problem in this snippet (see the console).

Any clue ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    codetoinject = '<div contenteditable="true">Editable text 2</div>'


    $(document).on("click", "#abutton", function (event) {
        console.log("Ok");
        $('#receptionarea').append(codetoinject);   
    })
})


$('.editablediv').blur(function () {
       console.log("save content with Ajax");
       // Ajax code
});
```

```css
#abutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abutton">
Click here
</div>

<div id="receptionarea">

<div class="editablediv" contenteditable="true">Editable text 1</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.blur` function is only being applied to elements with the `editablediv` class, which you are not giving to the dynamically added `div`. Also, you'll need to modify the way you are setting up the `blur` event handler to use event delegation for dynamically added elements.

Also, you can set up a `click` event handler directly on your button. There's no need to use event delegation there.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#abutton').on("click", function (event) {
    $("#receptionarea").append('<div contenteditable="true" class="editablediv">Editable text 2</div>');   
  });
 
  // You must set up event delegation for dynamically
  // added elements to get hooked up to events.
  $("div").on("blur",'.editablediv', function () {
    console.log("save content with Ajax");
    // Ajax code
  });
});
```

```css
#abutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid;
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abutton">Click here</div>

<div id="receptionarea">
  <div class="editablediv" contenteditable="true">Editable text 1</div>
</div>
```